# Change Base layer of Mapbox map in IOS dynamically

Tags: ios, mapbox

i scanned through the docs but couldn't find a reference to this. How can we change the base layer of a map box map dynamically, i.e. like Mapkit maps offering Satellite, Street etc.

Need this for IOS SDK.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (segment.selectedSegmentIndex){
            case 0:{
                [self.mapboxmapView setHidden:true forTileSource:self.satelliteSource];
                [self.mapboxmapView setHidden:false forTileSource:self.streetSource];
                break;
            }
            case 1:{
                [self.mapboxmapView setHidden:true forTileSource:self.streetSource];
                [self.mapboxmapView setHidden:false forTileSource:self.satelliteSource];
                break;
            }

}
```

After playing around with the code/docs i managed to get this by adding a segmentedbutton on the mapview and hiding/showing the mapsource based on the selection by user.

Also, You will need a paid mapbox account with 2 projects created on your dashboard, one configured with base layer as Satellite and other as Streetmap. Both the Tile sources need to be configured with their respective mapIds.

Comment: You can also see a good example of doing this in the sample app Mapbox Me that's linked from the Mapbox docs: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-me